# How can I use alt-n (˜) as a keyboard shortcut in Atom?

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, atom-editor

When I have:

```
  'alt-n': 'atomic-emacs:forward-paragraph'
```

and I type `alt-n`, I get this character: ˜. Can I either get Atom to recognize it or OS X to stop creating it?

I also tried

```
  '˜': 'atomic-emacs:forward-paragraph'
```

but that also didn't work.

Comment: What keyboard layout are you using? German keyboards use Alt-N for tilde.

Comment: "U.S." according to System Preferences. On Macbook built-in keyboard that was purchased in US.